# iOS: Black Status Bar when loading image is shown

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I load my app and have the black status bar shown while my loading (Default.png) is shown? Currently it always uses the grey status bar, but changes to black when my app finally loads.

I already have

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
```

in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your applications info.plist file, add the key `UIStatusBarStyle` and choose your desired style from the options. If you do this you don't need to set the style on didFinishLaunching.

This should be in the default info.plist in my opinion, but I'm sure there's a good reason why it isn't.

More information [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW4).

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful, I haven't checked, to change the style of status bar in .plist file in your application.